# Iterate over set of dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Currently I'm implementing data base using PostgreSQL. I have the following database(Hope that ER-diagram fully describes it) [image]

What do you need to know about this database is that friend can take a rest and have a holiday that is presented in a `holiday` table  by friend's `id`, `start_date` and `end_date`.

I want to create a PostgreSQL query that will find dates, when exactly `N` friends had a holiday. I'm confused with iterating over period between start and end date.(Every solution that will help with this query is okay).

Example: assume `holiday` table to have such a content

```
(1, '2012-05-23', '2012-05-27', 1)
(2, '2012-05-23', '2012-05-24', 2)
(3, '2012-05-24', '2012-05-26', 3)
```

Assume that `friend` table contain these three friends.

The output for `number of friends = 3` will be '2012-05-24'.

For `number of friends = 2` will be ('2012-05-23', '2012-05-25', '2012-05-26').

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-srf.html) to generate a list of all the dates between the earliest `start_date` and the latest `end_date` and then `LEFT JOIN` that to `holiday` to find all the friends who were on holiday on a given date. You can then count them and filter by the result. For example, to find the days on which 2 friends were on holiday:

```
SELECT dates.d AS "date", COUNT(*) AS num_on_holiday
FROM GENERATE_SERIES((SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM holiday),
                     (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM holiday),
                     '1 day'::interval) dates(d)
LEFT JOIN holiday h ON dates.d BETWEEN h.start_date AND h.end_date
GROUP BY dates.d
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY dates.d
```

Output:

```
date                    num_on_holiday
2012-05-23 00:00:00+01  2
2012-05-25 00:00:00+01  2
2012-05-26 00:00:00+01  2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=75e60e302b6864f55a65e8838a65d065)